# How do I use external storage drive in a PeerTube instance?

Tags: linux, debian

Should I move the peertube folder to the external drive and link it in `/var/www/peertube`? Or maybe modify the production.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to `rsync` your storage directory (`/var/www/peertube/storage`) to the other device and mount it at that location (ie. `/var/www/peertube/storage`). If you do through `production.yml`, you might have to update nginx/other conf (not sure, though) and have to update your configs while migrating again.
Please feel free to edit this if any one has a better solution.